# PDO rollback if affected rows are 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I create a PDO Database class to manage connections to the db, query's and transactions. I want to execute all the query's in one transaction, so if one throw an error, the others rollback.

Firs i create the update, delete or insert statement to run, and add the query with a function.

```
public function addQuery($entity)
    {
        $this->stack[] = $entity;
    }
```

Then i commit all the querys in the array:

```
public function commit()
    {
        self::beginTransaction();

        try {

            foreach ($this->stack as $entity) {
                $entity->execute();
            }
            self::commitTransaction();
            return true;        
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            self::rollbackTransaction();
            return false;
        }
}
```

This are the functions that i use:

```
protected function beginTransaction()
{
  $this->dbo->beginTransaction();
}


protected function commitTransaction()
{
  $this->dbo->commit();
}

protected function rollbackTransaction()
{
  $this->dbo->rollBack();
}
```

I tried making two updates. The firs that will update a row, and the second will affect 0 rows. But my function don't roll back the firs update.

Comment: Having 0 affected rows is not an error, how are you doing the rollback in that case?

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you catch an error with `catch (Exception $e)` then execute a rollback.

If you want to consider an SQL statement that affects 0 rows an error then you could do the following:

```
public function commit()
{
    self::beginTransaction();

    try {

        foreach ($this->stack as $entity) {
            $entity->execute();

            # If the statement affected 0 rows, then throw an error
            #   that will trigger a rollback
            if ( $entity->rowCount() == 0 ) {
               throw new \Exception("0 rows affected.");
            }
        }
        self::commitTransaction();
        return true;        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        self::rollbackTransaction();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Cautionary note** This could have very unexpected consequences as certain statements (like SELECT) affect 0 rows and then would trigger a ROLLBACK.

Hope this help!